# put text to div with dropdown option

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code and its not working. I want to put the selected text to my selected-locations div. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
    <select name='available_locations' class='select-location'>
        <option value='Germany'>Germany</option>
        <option value='Venice'>Venice</option>
        <option value='Spain'>Spain</option>
    </select>

    <div id='selected-locations'>

    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.select-location').change(function(){

                        var location = $( this ).attr( 'value' );
                        alert( location );
                        //new_text = $('#selected-locations').val() + location;
                        $('div.selected-locations').text( location );


        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read up on [css selectors](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/selectors/) and [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

```
$('div.selected-locations').text( location );
```

should be

```
$('div#selected-locations').text( location );
```

OR

```
<div id='selected-locations'>

</div>
```

shoould be

```
<div class='selected-locations'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
$('.select-location').change(function(){
    var location = $('.select-location option:selected').val();
    $('div#selected-locations').text(location);
});
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/F3A62/

A few things needed to change with your code:

1. change `$('div.selected-locations')` to `$('div#selected-locations')` ... period to hash
2. use the `option:selected`
3. use the `val()`

Answer (score 0):

use
    $('#selected-locations').text(location );
 You need to use # as selected-locations is a id not a css class.